# Python wordcloud color by term frequency

Tags: python, keyword-argument, word-cloud

I new in python and I a using wordcloud pkg.

I generated a word cloud by frequencies that I have in a dict `frequencies` with keys=words and values=frequencies of the words.

The wordcloud can receive a function in the `color_funct` parameter. Such function can be used to make your own colormap for the words on the cloud. As example I used `my_tf_color_func`.

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color="white", max_words=1000, mask=motog3_coloring,
max_font_size=1000, random_state=1,  relative_scaling=.6, regexp="\w[\%\-\(\)\w']+",
collocations=False, color_func=my_tf_color_func)
```

In `my_tf_color_func` I want to color each word according to its frequency in the attribute `frequencies`. I now that I can do something like bellow in `my_tf_color_func`, given the report [on this issue](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud/issues/88)

```
def my_tf_color_func(word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None, **kwargs):
         return "hsl(%d, 80%%, 50%%)" % (360 * frequencies[word])
```

But the dict `frequencies` has to be passed, how can I do that? Where and how I must pass the dict `frequencies` to be able to use it in `my_tf_color_func`.

I tried in some ways but I could not.

Many Thanks

Comment: Because you don't control the call site of the function, I don't think you can. But there's nothing stopping you from using it has you have defined so long as `frequencies` is in scope. Your function is no longer pure, and that is something worth recognizing and considering, but it should work fine. You might be interested in the concept of functors, which are essentially functions with state implemented with a class having a `__call__` attribute.

Comment: Hi @ryachza, I have a `main` and some functions in my project, including one to the wordcloud generator function where the wordcloud call is in. `frequencies` is not a global attribute, it is an attribute inside the wordlcoud generator function. So I must pass it to `my_tf_color_func` to be able to use it in there.

Comment: I added an answer with a couple of options to tie the dictionary and the function explicitly, but Python is pretty liberal with its scoping (something I actually dislike) so it should be possible to get `frequencies` in scope a number of ways. Without seeing more code I can't make a recommendation, though.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the option to create a function inside another function and I do that and it works. I disliked it too but it was the only way to do what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to pass the dict frequencies? The information is contained in font_size (mostly, at least).

Answer (score 5):

You could close over it explicitly using something like this:

```
def my_tf_color_func(dictionary):
  def my_tf_color_func_inner(word, font_size, position, orientation, random_state=None, **kwargs):
    return "hsl(%d, 80%%, 50%%)" % (360 * dictionary[word])
  return my_tf_color_func_inner

wordcloud = WordCloud(...,color_func=my_tf_color_func(frequencies))
```

An alternative for explicitly stateful function-like objects would be something like:

```
class MyColorFunctor():
  def __init__(self,frequencies):
    self.frequencies = frequencies

  def __call__(self,word,font_size,position,orientation,random_state=None,**kwargs):
    return "hsl(%d, 80%%, 50%%)" % (360 * self.frequencies[word])

wordcloud = WordCloud(...,color_func=MyColorFunctor(frequencies))
```